# I want to use fabric to execute a shell script

Tags: fabric

I want to use fabric to execute a shell script to start or restart some process, like this:

```
fab -H 192.168.1.111 restart
```

The fabric file contains the following:

```
def restart():
with cd('/home/'):
run('./restart')
```

The output seem to be a success, but when I check the process it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fabric default configuration, it cannot run any background processes. See documentation:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/faq.html

I am assuming './restart' is a script to restart some daemon processes. When fabric ends this task, the main process will exits. So will the subprocess generated by the main one. So you won't see it running after you log in again.

Try to use 'screen', and it will keep the process alive